# GET request via CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have CURL script as below:

```
$url= 'https://www.test.com/test.php';
$msg=?p1={1250.feed}&p2={jt2221}&p3={1330}&p4={1234567890}&p5={2016-02-04 20:05:34}&p6={New York}; 

$url .= $msg;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($http_status);
var_dump($result);
```

the full string url and message , when I copy/past on Chrome web browser the remote PHP file receives well. When same url+message sent by PHP script not works. I guess the problem is first the remote domain is HTTPS , second seems curly brackets and space disturbs the CURL request.I tried `urlencode($msg)` function then got Error 404 . On success sent message , remote PHP returns `{"Code":null,"Msg":"."}` as ACK

Comment: try to turn off the flag `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false, and add a browser agent as well `CURLOPT_USERAGENT`, just search it in the net you'll get both of those no problem

Comment: I added those lines :
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36'); I am getting now Bad Request

HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `urlencode`, you'll just want to encode the values, not the whole query string. An efficient way to do this (and keep your query data in neat arrays) is with [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$url= 'https://www.test.com/test.php?';

$data = array('p1' => '{1250.feed}',
              'p2' => '{jt2221}',
              'p3' => '{1330}',
              'p4' => '{1234567890}',
              'p5' => '{2016-02-04 20:05:34}',
              'p6' => '{New York}',);

$msg = http_build_query($data);

$url .= $msg;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($http_status);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: 'p6' => '{New York}',); is last comma need in last array after York?

Comment: No, that is just a habit, it makes it easier if you add any more values but otherwise doesn't make any difference. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2829581/628267) if you are keen for more discussion of the topic.

Comment: Bingo,  Ghost's CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER need to add , John's full code all works now. Just need un-comment CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER line

Comment: Nice work. Disabling SSL verification should be a temporary workaround, I recommend you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16495053/628267) to get your script working in a secure fashion.

Comment: I got your advice, modified as below, and works
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);